# user from admins group can't launch app as administrator

Tags: windows, admin, user-permissions

i have user with same rights as administrator. This user is in administrator group. The problem is that i can start my program only with "*run as administrator*",  so i can't simply run it after one click. How can user run program as administrator by default ?

i use **windows 10** x64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to local policy , Local Policies -> Security Options -> user account control run all administrators in admin approval mode -> disable

[image]

or go to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System set **EnableLUA** value 0